# Affiliation relation transitive?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ are two $C^*$-algebras such that $A\subset B$. If an operator $T$ is affiliated with $A$, then does it imply that $T$ is also affiliated with $B$?

As per my intuition, I think it is true but i can't verify using the definition.

**Definition:** An operator $T$ is said to be affiliated with $A$ if $z_T=T(1 + T^*T)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\in M(A)$, where $M(A)$ denotes the multiplier algebra of $A$, and $(1 + T^*T)^{-\frac{1}{2}}A$ is linearly dense in $A$.

This affiliation relation is denoted by $T\eta A$.

Now, if $T\eta A$, then by definition, $z_T\in M(A)\subset M(B)$ and $(1 + T^*T)^{-\frac{1}{2}}A$ is linearly dense in $A$. Does it follow that $(1 + T^*T)^{-\frac{1}{2}}B$ is linearly dense in $B$?

Help in any direction will be highly appreciated!

Comment: I put an (wrong) answer, but I misread your question! I thought you wanted $z_TB$ to be dense in $B$, my bad. I do have a question though: where is $T$ supposed to be?

Comment: Cosider $A$ and $B$ as concrete $C^*$-algebras, that is, embedded in $B(H)$, the space of all bounded linear operators on some Hilbert space $H$. Then, $T$ is a closed operator acting on $H$.